# Delete specific value and subsequent row in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I want to `delete` specific `rows` in a `pandas` `df`. I want to remove a `row` based on an undesired value plus the subsequent `row`. For the following `df` I want to remove the `row` where `Code == 'Cat'` plus the subsequent `row`. Below is my attempt.

```
import pandas as pd
```

import pandas as pd

```
d = ({
    'Code' : ['Foo','Bar','Cat','Foo','Foo'],
    'Int' : ['x','y','a','a','x'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(d)


df = df[df.Code.shift()!='Cat']

  Code Int
0  Foo   x
1  Bar   y
2  Cat   a
4  Foo   x
```

Intended Output:

```
  Code Val
0  Foo   x
1  Bar   y
2  Foo   x
```

Comment: `df[~(df.Val.eq('x') | df.Val.shift(1).eq('x'))]` ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `~` operator (logical **NOT**) and `|` operator (logical **OR**):

```
df[~(df.Code.eq('Cat') | df.Code.shift(1).eq('Cat'))]

  Code Int
0  Foo   x
1  Bar   y
4  Foo   x
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way:

```
df = df[~((df['Code'] == 'Cat') | (df['Code'].shift(1) == 'Cat'))]
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
  Code Val
0  Foo   x
1  Bar   y
4  Foo   x
```